# 5 Minute Builds for Titanium Android Application Installer

Tags: android, macos, titanium

Can't seem to find a solution here, running Lion and at one point early last week my builds were taking the usual time (less than a minute). All of the sudden my builds are taking over five minutes every time I run the application installer (I do not recall changing any configurations).

It seems to be compiling all code completely, I'm not sure exactly what it's doing, but I assume there's something fundamentally wrong with my environment.

Initially used brew to install my android-sdk/uninstalled those and installed through Titanium.

I'm using Titianium Mobile SDK 1.76 (out of necessity) with a Samsung Galaxy.

Let me know if I need to post the whole stack trace while building (really long so I'll throw a few items on here)

```
[TRACE] Writing out AndroidManifest.xml
[DEBUG] /usr/local/android_sdk/platform-tools/aapt package -m -J 
/trunk/build/android/gen -M     
/trunk/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml -S   
/trunk/build/android/res -I     
/usr/local/android_sdk/platforms/android-7/android.jar

[INFO] Compiling Android Resources... This could take some time
[DEBUG] creating unsigned apk: /trunk/build/android/bin/app-unsigned.apk
[DEBUG] from resource zip => assets/Resources/data/Auburn.txt <- This line for almost all resources
[DEBUG] from JAR /Library/Application     
Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.6.v20120320183239/android/titanium.jar =>   org/apache/Commons-NOTICE.txt
```

These are a few of the lines that I'm noticing that didn't seem to be around when things were running as they should.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Did a clean install with Mountain Lion's release, and this issue has resolved. There was obviously something fundamentally wrong with my environment, but if anyone knows what may have happened, please still throw it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have also this problem, but, it is solve when I Undo my tiapp.xml file. and Uninstall my app from Android Emulator and also delete Build file from Project File Directory and then run this is running Properly....

Cheers..

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete noob when it comes to Titanium. Could you explain this process?

Undo the tiapp.xml how?
What build file?

Comment: Open you Project Folder(where you Store Project)--> Build(folder)--> Delete Android folder

Clean the project and Run in you Emulator

Comment: Still no dice. I actually cleaned once, but now clean is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit tiapp.xml, the entire app needs to recompile.  You probably aren't touching the file that much, so it shoudn't say "Tiapp.xml change, recompiling..hold tight" or whatever it says in the build console.

Are you running on a phone or the emulator?  If you're debugging and not using breakpoints, selecting 'run' instead of 'debug' will build it faster.  Also, you technically shouldn't have to relaunch the run configuration each time; the whole point of that fastdev server thing is so that you can hit home (on the emulator) and relaunch the app without clicking 'run' from studio.

Comment: Using a tablet...if I run fastdev, does it have to be from inside the studio console or can it be from my Terminal?

Comment: i don't think you can use fastdev with a physical device, and I believe it has to be within the studio console.  It launches automatically when you launch an emulator run configuration.

Comment: Right, that's what I was assuming. I figured it was just for the emulator.